# using gnome-disks/terminal to format usb drive in ubuntu 12.10, FAT32

Tags: 12.10, usb-drive, format, disk-utility, fat32

I know its a duplicate question, but I couldn't find a answer that would have satisfied me..

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10, You know I was holding with the LTS but couldn't resist all those new enhancements either. So now the Disk Utility is [gone](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1013885).

So some existing posts on "how to format a usb" refer to using Disks, selecting **More Actions** and then **Format**... I don't know if I am doing right? [see here.](http://www.screencast.com/t/rNmULxY0ZfLJ)

and then I go for **Edit Partition Type** and now I see a lot of option for FAT32. 
[Which one to select?](http://www.screencast.com/t/SgTqeUoOd)

And If I use terminal- Is this correct? I need citation.

```
$sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
```

I also tried using [gparted](http://gparted.org/), but It wont allow me formating. [See here](http://www.screencast.com/t/4MjPZwcL0m18).

I'd prefer to use terminal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GParted is by far the best option. The picture you showed is normal, as you have to unmount the partition before you can format it.

The terminal command you gave, at a guess, might just create a new partition table of type 'vfat'.

Comment: this command used to work with redhat, I think some more info will be helpful.
_new partition table of type 'vfat'_ - why do I have to worry about that?

Comment: And yes thanks Gparted works, I am felling so dumb.. +1vote up for that :)

Comment: It would format the partition table, which organises the disk, and vfat would be alright for that,but it might not create any partitions. If Gparted worked, your problem should be solved ;-)

Comment: yes, I wanna know the best of the three, and preferably using terminal. So I shall wait for more answers.